# DataContract for serializing interface subclasses

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

My situation is something like this :
There's a service method that should accept a collection of some interface. 
The client has several classes implementing that interface. For argument's sake there might be only one, the point is that they only add private members. 
I don't want the service to know the implementing types in the client. 
So is there a way for me to create another subclass of that interface in the service that will act as a DataContract in order to properly serialize/deserialize the existing classes I have in my client? Or maybe I need a different solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a base class on your client side, where all of the subclasses that implements that interface will inherit from, and add a [KnownTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) for each one

```
[KnownType(typeof(Subclass1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Subclass2))]
[DataContract]
public class BaseClass : ISomeInterface
{

}
```

Comment: And make this my DataContract? And what should I do on my server?

Comment: @Nadavrbn yes, make it your data contract. your server now must know the BaseClass inorder to serialize/deserialize it properly. Check out [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/06/06/618877.aspx) post to understand the concept better

Comment: I see, what I'm looking for is the server not knowing about those types because it will create strong coupling.

Comment: @Nadavrbn It isn't possible for the service to serialze/deserialze something it doesn't know. about The strong coupling - for that purpose exactly the `KnownTypes` feature is for. it allows you to reduce your coupling by the server only knowing the BaseClass in complie time, while the classes implementing your interface are known only in run-time. If you want to reduce your coupling even more, move them to an entirely different assembly neither the server or the client. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751512.aspx) detailed example.

Comment: @Nadavrbn if it still doesn't answer your needs then either you or me are missing something ...

Comment: Actually it would have been a lot easier for me to turn the interface into an abstract class, but the problem is that it's subclasses need to inherit from other classes.

Comment: What I did is create a shared class and on my client just parsed the unknown types to the shared type by copying the properties. Thank you very  much! BTW I see you were in MAAV. I'm from right next door. ;)

Comment: @Nadavrbn Cool! say hi to everyone for me :)